# How to use C I/O redirection on a Mac?

Tags: c, xcode

I'm experimenting with I/O redirection in C; I redirect the Standard Input so that I can print a number contained in a txt file on the console.

```
int main() {
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("The number is %d.", number);
}
```

In Xcode, I go the Products folder and I double click on the executable file to fire up a console. I issue this line:

```
./main.c < number.txt
```

The console prints out a number, but not the correct one. If you wish, download this simple project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7sgpt4xl8ahuad/StackOverflow_Question.zip?dl=0). What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

**Updates**

- I'm experiencing the same issue with a `CSV` file;
- I checked the return value of `scanf()` and it's equal to 0.
- The number contained in the files is `4` (I changed it into `5` recently), but the output of the shell is `The number is 1726119990.`

Comment: "a csv file containing a number"? If it's just a number in there, then it's not a csv. it's just a text file with a number. show exactly what's in this .csv

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MarcB. Can't a CSV file have just 1 row/column? I just tested the program using a txt file and the shell is still printing the same number. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your executable really called `main.c`? And check the return value of your `scanf()` call. Is it `1`?

Comment: Yes, the C file is really called `main.c`. The return value is not 1. I'm wondering why. Thanks for your help @cremno.

Comment: Are you typing in a shell (Terminal.app), or XCode's console?

Comment: @CeceXX: csv = comma separated values - you have neither commas nor multiple values, so by definition, it's not a csv.

Comment: I'm typing in the Terminal, thanks for question @kdhp.

Comment: @kdhp: Neither. OPs mistake is: `I double click on the executable file to fire up a console` - I'm not using OS X, so somebody else has to tell them the correct way.

Comment: More on the point cermno was getting at -- if your "the C file is really called `main.c`", are you sure it's been compiled?  You cannot run ".c" files like a shell script. (unlike Python for example).  What *is* your output for the program, verbatim?  Also, always be sure to terminate your printf strings with a `\n`.  The program should flush stdout when exiting w/o one, but it still may cause confusion.

Comment: @CeceXX  It would seem to me that you are typing commands into the standard-input of your program, not into a shell.  Try executing it and typing `4` (the contents of `myNumber.csv`) instead of `./main.c < myNumber.csv`.

Comment: Thanks @BrianMcFarland, the output of the program is `The number is 1726119990. `.  @kdhp That works fine, the number displayed is `4`.

Comment: if you do `cat number.txt`  (or whatever the file name was) what does it show?

Comment: Thanks @CyberSpock the return value is 0. Instead, when I type in the number instead of redirecting the Standard Input, it is 1.

Comment: sounds like there is something in the file besides your number since scanf fails to parse.

Comment: you are supposed to to run the .exe not the main.c file, i.e. `./main < number.txt`

Comment: That's a great point @CyberSpock! It still doesn't seem to parse the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are doing something along the lines of starting your program and getting a blank line (which is the `scanf()` reading from stdin) then you write `./main.c < number.txt` which means you are not piping the file with the value into your program, instead scanf is reading the string and since it doesn't find a number it returns 0.

What you need to do is to create a console window so you see the $ in front and then go to the directory where your exe is and write `./main < number.txt`

Comment: Thanks! I opened up the Terminal.app, I typed in `cd` plus the directory containing the exe file (aka the Debug folder). As you suggested, I issued `./main < number.txt` and I get `-bash: number.txt: No such file or directory`. What can I do? I appreciate your help!

Comment: create the file `number.txt` file in the same directory or supply the full path to the existing number.txt on your command line e.g. `./main < /usr/someone/somewhere/number.txt`

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like a charm. Instead of `main`, I typed the executable file name instead (in this case, `StackOverflow_Question`).

Comment: Thanks again! Just a small question: what happens if I have two C files (`file1.c`, `file2.c`) and two input/output files (`input.txt`, `output.txt`). I want to create a pipe and redirect the Standard Input/Output, just like this: `(./file1 | ./file2) < input.txt > output.txt`. Does your answer still apply? The C files are two, and the executable file is only one. How does the console tell which one to run first? Thanks!

Comment: @CeceXX you can have any number of .c files in a executable. The resulting object files from the .c files are linked together into one executable. The entry point in the the program is the main() function so you cannot have two main() functions one in each .c file.